# Close safari automatically

Tags: safari

Safari can ben opened from a terminal automatically

```
open -a safari
```

When comes to close it, I have to press 'Cmd+Shift+W' or click quit option in dock

Is it possible to quit safari automatically? like

```
close -a safari
```

Comment: How about `killall Safari`?

Answer (score 2):

One of the Apple-supported ways to do it is the following **AppleScript** command:

```
tell app "Safari" to quit
```

Use the following one-liner to run the same thing from your **shell:**

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Safari" to quit'
```

Or, use the bundle ID if that’s more your thing:

```
osascript -e 'tell app id "com.apple.Safari" to quit'
```